# Facebook Realtime Updates for Disputes, Refunds and Chargebacks

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-payment-dialog

What will the data sent via a real time update contain, in the event of a dispute ??
if this below is for an order fulfillment..

```
{ 
  "object": "payments",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "296989303750203",
      "time": 1347996346,
      "changed_fields": [
          "actions"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

will the changed_fields array contain "disputes" instead of "actions"?

Nowhere is it explicitly stated, this is just my best guess and Im not entirely comfortable with implementing a system based on guesses.

My best guess for refunds and/or chargebacks is that it would contain "actions"?

Can anyone provide clarity? it would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For disputes, `changed_fields` will contain value `disputes` if your payment subscription has `disputes` field.

Whenever an `payment` update occurs, facebook will call your server real time. In POST data, `changed_fields` will contain changed parameter. For example, suppose you are subscribed for user data with field value name, whenever user updates his name, your server will be called with `name` in `changed_fields` array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fql the payment to find if it's disputed. At least, judging from this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/disputesrefunds/

Also, check this

[Local Currency - How to handle real time updates for refunds, disputes and chargebacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355023/local-currency-how-to-handle-real-time-updates-for-refunds-disputes-and-charg)

Comment: It's better to quote or summarize instead of write only a link, because if the page is removed your answer will be quite useless.