# Local Currency - How to handle real time updates for refunds, disputes and chargebacks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-payments

I'm a bit confused on how we are expected to handle real time updates for refunds, chargebacks and disputes..

I've subscribed to both the actions and disputes real time updates fields but when a dispute is filed by a user the changed_fields array contains 'actions' and not disputes?!

This is an example of the JSON response we get:

```
{"object":"payments","entry":[{"id":"409105399200862","time":1377079956,"changed_fields":["actions"]}]}
```

Surely the changed_fields should be set to 'disputes' as that's the field I've subscribed to and is the thing that has actually changed? The issue here is that when I then go and look up this transaction from the graph api if both dispute and actions data is present how can I know which one has changed? I've read through all the documentation at least 10 times and it doesn't seem to explain how to do this.

Also if a user files a dispute and we or facebook resolve it should it not be removed from the graph api response or are we expected to keep track of this somehow?

There's a lot of unanswered questions floating around stackoverflow regarding the new local currency system so it would really great if we could get some clarification for once :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has acknowledged the bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2074441772694571?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fbugs%2F2074441772694571&refid=9 and is apparently working on a fix.