# Facebook-initiated refunds/chargebacks realtime update action/field

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I'm developing Facebook app with payments enabled and I want to get some alert when Facebook-initiated refund or chargeback happens.

My question is what type of action/field will I receive via realtime updates on `payments` subscription in `changed_fields` array, '**actions**' or '**disputes**'?

I can't read it from documentation...

> As with disputes, you will be notified via a realtime update when
>   Facebook refunds an order. Also, as before, additional information
>   will be added to the Graph API return data for the payment. Rather
>   than an additional disputes array, there will be a refund object added
>   to the actions array, signifying the payment has been refunded.

And is there any way to test it without actually buying stuff for real money and asking Facebook to refund?

Just to clarify, question is not about user disputes, but about **Facebook-Initiated** refunds and chargebacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changed field in the update is **'actions'**.

The "realtime updates" section of the payment object documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/payment/) gives refunds and chargebacks as examples of cases the field can be update after completion.

Also, the "Handling Disputes and Refunds" page you quote, while not directly mentioning anything about the details of the realtime update, does have examples about the Graph API returns for transactions after a Facebook-initiated refund or chargeback has happened, in both of those examples, the refund/chargeback information has been added as a new entry to the actions field.

I do not believe there is a way to test disputes or Facebook-initiated refunds/chargebacks except with real money payments, but you **can** refund a non-disputed test payment yourself and that results in a realtime update that should be identical with one initiated by Facebook.

Comment: I was concerned about changed fields because there were some bugs before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355023/local-currency-how-to-handle-real-time-updates-for-refunds-disputes-and-charg). It's a pity that there is no way to test disputes/refunds without real payments.